# getStaticProperties of ReflectionClass returns inherited class properties

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
class A {
    public static $a = '1';
}
class B extends A {
    public static $b = '2';
}
$refclass = new ReflectionClass('B');
foreach ($refclass->getStaticProperties() as $key => $property)
    echo $key;
```

This code prints $a and $b.
Is there any way to get the class properties without getting the inherited parents class properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($refclass->getStaticProperties() as $key => $property)
    if ($refclass->getProperty($key)->getDeclaringClass() == $refclass) {
        echo $key;
    }
}
```

Or, perhaps more elegant:

```
$props = array_filter($refclass->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC), function ($prop) use ($refclass) {
    return $prop->getDeclaringClass() == $refclass;
});
```

Comment: Did you test this because i get this error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function getDeclaringClass() on a non-object"?

Comment: My bad, I *assumed* `getStaticProperties` returns `ReflectionProperty[]` like `getProperty` does... documentation wasn't helpful and PHP isn't consistent... :(

Comment: Also check out `$refclass->getProperties(ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC)`, I'm not sure whether this might already exclude inherited properties or not. Again, documentation not helping much. >:-(